# How to disable automatic creation of Azure SQL Database Resources through Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

I have the issue, that when I run my ASP.NET Project that it automatically creates a new Azure SQL Database (Gen 5 with 2 virtual cores for 340€/month). This is not specified anywhere I am nowhere in my code using anything like "context.Database.CreateIfNotExists" or "Migrate".

The connection string in the CloudConfiguration points to a Database Server that exists in Azure. Nevertheless, I don't want it to automatically create a new Azure SQL Database on that server.

Strange thing is, that it creates the new Azure SQL Database but it does not create any tables in it, so the Migrations from Entity Framework seem to not be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your app with a user who can't create databases, and see where it fails.

> Only the administrators (Server admin login or Azure AD administrator)
>   and the members of the dbmanager database role in the master database
>   have permission to execute the CREATE DATABASE and DROP DATABASE
>   statements.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution. But anyway: why does Entity Framework in the background create a new database resource in Azure with a pretty high tier which costs a lot? Is this an economic trick to earn money? I think it would be much better if you would be notified about something like this.

Comment: Yes.  That's a workaround and a troubleshooting idea, not a solution.  EF doesn't just create databases without being told to.

Comment: But in our case it did. And it is reproducible.

Comment: Do you have a repro you can share?  There's a problem that should be fixed _somewhere_.

Comment: It is enough to create a new ASP.NET App using Entity Framework. Let the connection string point to a database server which already exists in Azure, but choose a database name which not already exists. It will create a new Azure SQL Database "Gen5v2".

Comment: So creating the database if it doesn't exist is the default database initialization behavior of EF.  So you'll generally want to pre-create the database or customize the database initialization to change the SKU or to use an existing Elastic Database Pool.

Comment: Did you find a solution?